# Convert the pose bone matrix to a local matrix

Tags: python, animation

I need to convert a pose matrix to a local matrix.
I do it like this:

```
armature_object.convert_space(pose_bone, pose_bone.matrix, 'POSE', 'LOCAL')
```

And it works.
But if you turn off the Inherit Rotation checkbox on the bone, then this function will not take this into account.
I need to find a way to get around this limitation.
The only thing that occurred to me was to write my own function convert_space.
But I do not know how to make it.